# How to make GameLift AWS Game Sessions to run endlessly

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-ec2, amazon-gamelift

Good day everyone,

Would like to ask how to make game sessions to run forever after they are being activated? Because when game builds got deployed into cloud after a game was tested locally successfully and game sessions were activated from EC2 servers using GameLift Anywhere service, have noticed that it will last maximum only 3 days to be active after that they will be terminated automatically. Haven't founded any parameters to specify how long game session should last when being activated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, guessing that my company labels me as an engineer for a reason, implementation was to use terminationtime of the created game session information on the backend server(apparently it doesnt return termination time...) right after process reactivated (the process should start from getting auth token for compute) within GameLiftServerAPI sdk on the game server when old session is about to be terminated. As currently GameLift doesnt support multiple game sessions per compute process, but can be wrong. I admit that this implementation is not good, but thats the only thing I was awared of during using GameLift service, appreciate efforts of developers who worked on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).